# PL/SQL --next date based on Frequency

Tags: oracle, date

I am looking for a `oracle` Function or procedure to calculate next date based on an `Input Date` and `Frequency(Yearly,half yearly, Quarterly )`.

For example

```
Input Date     Frequency    Next Occurrence Date
1-Jan-2016     Quarterly     1-Apr-2016
1-Jan-2016     yearly        1-Jan-2017
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Oracle function `ADD_MONTHS( date, number_months )` to get monthly, quarterly, yearly results.

For example, next quarter would be 3 months.  So if the input date was the first  quarter you could use:

```
ADD_MONTHS( 01-JAN-2016, 3 )
```

to get the next quarter.

Example SQL:

```
select TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY') as "Input Date",
       'Quarterly' as "Frequency",
       ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 3) as "Next Occurrence Date"
from dual
union
select TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY') as "Input Date",
       'Yearly' as "Frequency",
       ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 12) as "Next Occurrence Date"
from dual
;
```

Results:

```
Input Date         Frequency Next Occurrence Date
------------------ --------- ------------------
01-JAN-16          Quarterly 01-APR-16
01-JAN-16          Yearly    01-JAN-17
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending @tale852150's answer a bit, you could use a case expression to translate the frequency into the number of months to add, assuming you have a known list of possible values:

```
add_months(input_date, case frequency
  when 'Quarterly' then 3
  when 'Half yearly' then 6
  when 'Yearly' then 12 else 0 end
```

Quick demo:

```
with t (input_date, frequency) as (
  select date '2016-01-01', 'Quarterly' from dual
  union all select date '2016-01-01', 'Half yearly' from dual
  union all select date '2016-01-01', 'Yearly' from dual
)
select input_date, frequency,
  add_months(input_date, case frequency
    when 'Quarterly' then 3
    when 'Half yearly' then 6
    when 'Yearly' then 12 else 0 end) as next_occurrence_date
from t;

INPUT_DATE FREQUENCY   NEXT_OCCURRENCE_DATE
---------- ----------- --------------------
2016-01-01 Quarterly   2016-04-01          
2016-01-01 Half yearly 2016-07-01          
2016-01-01 Yearly      2017-01-01
```